# Is Synchronized Blocking?

Tags: java, synchronized

In java, I have 2 threads in my client, one is controlling the network flow, the other one is processing the messages, draws game etc. What I am trying to do is when a packet comes, the network thread will call messageReceived method of the game thread, containing the message as parameter. Will it block networking thread if i make the function messageReceived as synchronized and there are 2 packets sequentally come before messageReceived function ends, or it doesn't block and my packet is lost because network thread couldn't call messageReceived function which is already being used by game thread ?

Comment: `synchronized` will block until the resource is released by the other thread.

Comment: thank you, so it will be safe to make messageReceived synchronized without the danger of packet loss.

Comment: Yes, but keep the synchronized blocks short. There won't be a problem as long as there is time to accept and process all packets sequentially so that no OS buffer fills up and loses the packets before you get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the synchronized keyword to sync a code section, then when another thread comes in that wants access to that section it will block until it can get access.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you're blocking on the IO thread. You want to only do light work on messageReceived() because of that ... perhaps only queue the message in some sort of FIFO for the processing thread to work on later. Your sync blocks should have as small a footprint as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If a thread calls a synchronized method in a class, all the other threads will be blocked to call any synchronized method in that class because the object lock is not available. If your messageReceived is not working on any shared resource then keep it non-synchronized. In case it is using some shared resource then try to minimized the synchronized code by wrapping that code in synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to solve a problem that could be easily avoided if you used a more mainstream design pattern such as the Observer Pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `synchronized` blocks a thread if the implicit lock has already locked by another thread. But there is a non-blocking alternative - `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` that is more flexible

```
Lock.tryLock()
```

- acquires the lock only if it is free at the time of invocation

and

```
Lock.tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)
```

- acquires the lock if it is free within the given waiting time and the current thread has not been interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to conceptualize but im more of a visual person. Heres a bit of code that helped me long ago understand what excatly syncorized did and how it worked. If you watch the output you will see when you add the synchronized attribute to the print function that you never see As and Bs mixed. but when you remove it you will see a much different output. It should be straight forward once you see it.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new ThreadA()).start();
        (new ThreadB()).start();
    }

    // try it with removing the synchronized:  public static void print(String str) {
    public static synchronized void print(String str) {
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
            System.out.print(str);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static class ThreadA extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                print("A");
            }
        }
    }
    public static class ThreadB extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                print("B");
            }
        }
    }
}
```